# Creating a personal marker information window Google Maps

Tags: android

I want to create my own information window by clicking on a marker as suggested on developers.google.com. But everything I tried does not work and the application does not work. Please tell me how to correctly use the proposed method and display your information window when you click on the marker?

Link to Google recommended solution
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows?hl=ru

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z9vA.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random"/>
    </ScrollView>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```